# Jquery Stepy Form Plugin jump to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I am using a jquery plugin ([Stepy](http://wbotelhos.com/stepy)) that breaks a form up into sections so longer forms can be tabbed. It works well except that when you click to a next step it will focus on the first visible input. The instructions for my form are above the inputs so the user has to scroll up to see them which isn't great.

I have tried changing line 205-

```
d = j.eq(max).find("#target");
```

and 209

```
d.first().focus(#target);
```

of the plugin which stopped the form focusing on the first input but can't get it to either jump to the top of the page or to an anchor. (The original plugin code is in the fiddle, see lines 205 and 209, line 144 also could need changing.)

I created an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/webthread/e4VHM/1/), you will need to scroll down to see the next/previous buttons.

Any help/ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it working.
I changed line 153 and 168 from

```
href: "javascript:void(0);",
```

to

```
href: "#",
```

Which does the trick for desktop, to make it work for mobile you need to comment out line 209

```
//d.first().select().focus();
```

because mobile will automatically scroll to a selected input.